# How to remove leading zeros from XML node values using xslt

Tags: xslt

In my env i am making two calls to get account details from different organization, and both organization return account details, but they are adding extra leading zeros in accountNumber, so my code is failing when i am comparing request and response account numbers, Is there any way to remove extra zeros from below xml using xslt.

```
<EAI>
    <SvcRS>
        <accountHeader>
            <errorHost>orgA</errorHost>
        </accountHeader>
        <accoutnDetails>
            <accountNumber>0000000111118800</accountNumber>
            <accountType>credit</accountType>
            <errorDetails>
                <code>111</code>
                <description>Account is not valid</description>
            </errorDetails>
        </accoutnDetails>
    </SvcRS>
    <SvcRS>
        <accountHeader>
            <errorHost>orgB</errorHost>
        </accountHeader>
        <accoutnDetails>
            <accountNumber>000111118800</accountNumber>
            <accountType>credit</accountType>
            <errorDetails>
                <code>0001</code>
                <description>Not enough balance</description>
            </errorDetails>
        </accoutnDetails>
    </SvcRS>
</EAI>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Which version of XSLT do you use/can you use? Is that `accountNumber` always an integer number or can contain letters as well?

Comment: I can use xslt 1.0 or 2.0, accountNumber is always integer value

Comment: @kekukeku You can use format-number function, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2 or later you can use `replace(., '^0+', '')` in the context of `xsl:template match="accountNumber"` to remove leading zeros with string operations (http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Nqn5Y3/1) or you can use `xs:integer(.)` to remove the leading zeros by converting that value inside of element to an integer (http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Nqn5Y3).

Comment: Hi I have checked, I am just getting node attribute values, not complete node

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring to, in the samples I linked to the input `<accountNumber>0000000111118800</accountNumber>` is transformed to `<accountNumber>111118800</accountNumber>` so that is the replacement you asked for. The linked snippets are XSLT 3 instead of XSLT 2 however, so if you want a complete XSLT 2 solution you need to spell out the `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` as `<xsl:template match="@* | node()"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>`, but that is not related to the task of manipulation the account number.

Comment: Thanks Martin for explanation and example, It is working for me now changing to XSLT 2.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `format-number` function as below:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(.//accountNumber, '#')"/>
```

Result:

```
111118800
```